# Analyse driving pattern from automotive dataset

Tags: clustering, geospatial-pdf, driving

I am trying to derive driving patterns from our automotive dataset. Our dataset has vehicle names along with their GPS points. One of the driving pattern I have read about is “hub and spoke” in which vehicles start and stop at the same location. Other vehicles like trucks will travel in the nights following a different pattern.

From my research, I understand that Kmeans clustering of data will not work on this data, as different vehicles might have different patterns. Just wondering whether any other ML algorithms would be effective in solving this problem? Because I have 1 million vehicles, if i consider all GPS points in a vehicle, that would be a massive dataset. Would it be better if i could restrict the GPS points based on some condition.

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by driving patterns?

Comment: @John Barca: An example would be some vehicles would start and stop in the same location, following a hub and spoke pattern. Other vehicles like trucks will travel in the nights following a different pattern.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of hub and spoke vs star models. But what are you trying to actually discover?  The question is very vague at the moment.

Comment: I am trying to discover the vehicles that follow that pattern (which means those that start and stop at the same location)

Comment: So, basically, you are trying to determine which vehicles might be under fleet management as distinct from private vehicles which would show a more chaotic pattern. What sort of temporal resolution does your dataset have? This is obviously relevant for determining start/stop. What is the sourcce of the dataset (if you can say). It's a very interesting question, but still lacking in enough information to give a useful answer, I think.

Comment: @JohnBarça:
I have the following fields:FleetId,StartTime,StopTime,Latitude and Longitude. A vehicle can have multiple StartTime, StopTime, Latitude and Longitude as it might start, travel some distance and stop. 
For example, there is a possibility that ambulances will start and stop in the same location, might  be hospital premises, identical to school buses. I have to cluster vehicles of this kind in a cluster.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.